# Sunken Moon Cakes

Tags: baking, chinese-cuisine

I made moon cakes for the first time at the weekend, but rather than the glazed apearance and firm texture they usually have, they sunk in the middle. Without building the dough equivalent of the great wall of china to help keep the filling in, is there another way I can 'reinforce' the walls to stop them sinking?

I used [this recipe](http://www.xiangcool.com/traditional-baked-moon-cake-recipe%EF%BC%8D%E4%BC%A0%E7%BB%9F%E6%9C%88%E9%A5%BC/):

> - 300g Low Protein flour
> - 250g Golden syrup
> - 70g Peanut oil
> - 1/2tsp Alkaline water
> - 1/8 Lemon juice from a whole lemon
> - Lotus paste
> - Pandan paste
> - Steamed Salted Egg Yolk (Steamed 10 mins under high heat)
>
> Egg wash
>    - 2 egg yolk plus 1 whole egg (lightly beaten)
>
> **Method**
>
> 1. Mix syrup, peanut oil and Alkaline water and lemon juice together, stir it well.
> 2. Slowly pour the sifted flour and knead into a fine dough.
> 3. Cover and rest it for 4-6 hours in the fridge. Better if you rest it overnight.
> 4. Mix the melon seed with the lotus paste. Weight the lotus paste 110g each and roll into a round ball.
> 5. If you intend to add 1 salted egg yolk, reduce the lotus paste to 80g each and wrapped the egg yolk in it.
> 6. Weight dough 55g each and roll into a ball.
> 7. Flatten the dough ball and place a lotus paste ball on top, wrap with it.
> 8. Dush some flour on the mooncake mould, knock out excess flour.
> 9. Place mooncake inside the mould, flatten dough to conform to shape of mould.
> 10. Knock the mooncake mould on solid surface and slowly remove the mooncake and place on a baking pan.
> 11. I apply egg wash twice on the moon cake, hence apply egg wash then bake it at pre-heated oven at 180c for 11 minutes.
> 12. Remove mooncake from oven and set aside to cool for at least 15mins.
> 13. Apply egg wash again and bake at preheated oven at 180c for 11mins.
> 14. Remove mooncake from oven, immediately transfer to wire rack to cool. Keep in air tight container and allow it to set. Serve after 1-2
>       days after the colour is uniform and the skin is soften and moist.

Comment: Providing the recipe and technique you used will get you better answers, it is hard to diagnose a problem without details.

Comment: Do you mean they're spreading (they stay closed, but the sides expand and naturally the middle sinks) or leaking? And I assume this is happening during baking?

Comment: The middle sunk and the sides spread out, like the dough lacked the strength to hold the filling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some tips:

Moon Cakes take lots of time. especially the dough for the shell. It's best if it sits in the fridge (wrapped, of course) for 24 - 36 hours before working, then is kneaded well to make it flexible before stretching. See these instructions from houseofannie.com. She's got it down. Note, in particular, the tips at the bottom for first-timers. Also note that her dough recipe is a little different from the one you used. It is possible that the recipe you used is fine, but these little cakes really benefit from practice with an experienced helper. Annie is a good substitute.
Instructions webpage here:
http://www.houseofannie.com/traditional-baked-mooncake-recipe/